# Число с плавающей точкой C++ printf()

Tags: c++, printf

```
printf("%e",pow(2.0,70));
```

Что нужно подставить вместо **%e** что бы вывести нормальное число без **E**, т.е большое длинное число.
спасибо

Comment: 1. Варианты форматирования можете посмотреть [тут][1]/ Например, f
2. printf - это все-таки не С++, это скорее уж Си
3. не "за место", а "вместо", не сочтите за придирку

[1]:http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
printf("%.10f", pow(2.0,70));
```

Comment: вывод должен быть такой 4722366482869645213696
А выводит кое-что другое

Comment: Хотя нет, все верно, это в задании ошибка

Comment: >вывод должен быть такой 4722366482869645213696

с чего вы взяли? 2 в 70-ой степени равно 1 180 591 620 717 411 303 424

Comment: Я решал задачу на http://acmp.ru/index.asp?main=task&id_task=40, и у меня возникли проблемы в точности, потом я проверил, ответ действительно 1 180 591 620 717 411 303 424, но при printf("%.10f", pow(2.0,3)); выводится какаято чепуха

Comment: >но при printf("%.10f", pow(2.0,3)); выводится какаято чепуха


почему чепуха? Все верно выводится - 8.0000000000

Comment: Да, все верно, это у меня ошибка былв, всесто 3 у меня было n-типа char:), а можно избавиться от .000000?

Comment: и еше при возведении в 70 степень он выдает не 1 180 591 620 717 411 303 424, а 1 180 591 620 717 411 303 424 00000

Comment: >а можно избавиться от .000000

вам же дали ссылку на статью о форматировании, почитайте ее. Это просто

Comment: @djdeniro Всегда будьте уверены, что тип данных способен вместить необходимое вам число в необходимой точности. Иначе будет неизбежно усечение. Можно читать здесь: http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/